# Angular 7 HttpClient Get Request undefined response

Tags: angular, rest, angular-httpclient

GET Request from API undefined error

Data is displayed but console show undefined error at line 46:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'detaljne' of undefined
and
ERROR Context PostComponent.html:46

JSON is nested in JSON-Server

TS

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import { Post } from "../post.model";
import { ServerService } from "../server.service";

@Component({
  selector: "post",
  templateUrl: "./post.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./post.component.css"]
})
export class PostComponent implements OnInit {
  post: Post[];

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private serverService: ServerService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getPost();
  }

  getPost(): void {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");
    this.serverService.getPosts(id).subscribe(post => (this.post = post));
  }
}
```

HTML

```html
<div *ngFor="let detaljne of post.detaljne" class="row-info">
   <p>{{ detaljne.name }}</p>
   <p>{{ detaljne.value }}</p>
</div>
```

post.model.ts

```
import { Detaljne } from "./detaljne.model";
import { Deserializable } from "./deserializable.model";

export class Post implements Deserializable {
  public id: number;
  public detaljne: Detaljne[];

  deserialize(input: any): this {
    Object.assign(this, input);
    this.detaljne = input.detaljne.map(detaljne =>
      new Detaljne().deserialize(detaljne)
    );
    return this;
  }
}
```

JSON

```
{
      "id": 1,
      "detaljne": [
        {
          "name": "Marka",
          "value": "Audi"
        },
        {
          "name": "Model",
          "value": "A6"
        }
      ]
    },
```

Comment: Try to use ``post?.detaljne`` in the ngFor to see if it works

Comment: I already tried but not helpful

Comment: Try to provide a demo to reproduce your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access a property of `post` in your `*ngFor`, but you don't check whether `post` itself exists yet.
To fix this you can use `*ngIf`

Using `*ngIf="post"` won't render the HTML element until post is defined.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="post">
  <div *ngFor="let detaljne of post.detaljne" class="row-info">
      <p>{{ detaljne.name }}</p>
      <p>{{ detaljne.value }}</p>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

*Note: You can't use `*ngFor` and `*ngIf` on the same element, so you use `<ng-container>` which is just a 'wrapper' that wont create an actual element on the DOM.*

Alternatively there's the safe navigation operator `?`, which is slightly different as it's like doing `post!== null ? product.detaljne: null`. Both options are valid, just pick the one that suits best :)

Comment: Instead of adding extra layer of `*ngIf`. It should be solved with `safe navigation operator (?.)`

Comment: Error is gone! Thank you @Jojofoulk! Can you tell me something about this error just to know for future?

Comment: Update the answer to explain what was going on :)

Comment: Aha, now it is clearer to me...thank you again @Jojofoulk

Comment: @Jojofoulk: adding an extra layer of ***ngIf** is not needed, see my answer.

Comment: I updated my comment and addressed that point. The two approaches differ slightly but they are both valid.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this, should be sufficiant, you don't need to add an extra layer of `*ngIf`:

```
<div *ngFor = "let detaljne of post?.fetchData">
  <p>{{ detaljne.name }}</p>
  <p>{{ detaljne.value }}</p>
</div>
```

**See this working demo:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-example-7ipt7m?file=app/app.component.ts

**Result:**

[image]

just replace:

```
post = {
  "id": 1,
  "fetchData": [
    {
      "name": "Marka",
      "value": "Audi"
    },
    {
      "name": "Model",
      "value": "A6"
    }
  ]
};
```

By:

```
post = null;
```

and you will not see any error with this method

Answer (score 0):

**The reason is it is taken some time to get the response. So use promises to delay until loading the data.**

```
this._customerService.getCustomers().subscribe(data => this.customers = data);
```

use this under promises.